# PC not recognizing gamecube controller with mayflash adapter

Tags: pc, nintendo-gamecube

So I got Mayflash's gamecube to usb adapter a while ago, and when I plug in my controller it doesn't show up anywhere on the computer. It recognizes the adapter though. I have one of the black third-party gamecube controllers, do those work with the adapter? Any advice would be helpful.

Comment: If the PC is recognizing the adapter, then chances are good it's not that, but the controller.  Do you have a different one you can try?

Comment: i have 2 of the same type, and neither work. i'll try to get one from a friend.

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but I had the same problem so it might be useful to someone.

I got two of those adapters, you need to connect the adapter to the computer after you connected the controller to the adapter. A third party controller shouldn't be a problem. I got one of those too, and it works too.

If the issue persist, try with a different controller and if there's still nothing, then chances are the adapter is defective.